# Angularjs: Html render as text

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have an Angularjs script to create a navigation Bar using users parameters.
The problem is that, when i try to render the html structure, it always displays as plain text

This is the script:

```
var app = angular.module('userData', []);

app.controller('showUserData', ['$scope', function($scope){
    $scope.userPar = JSON.parse(sessionStorage.userPar);
    $scope.navBar = createNavBar($scope.userPar);

    $scope.logOut = function(){
        alert('Out you go!');
    }

}]);

app.directive("otcNavbar", function(){
    return {
       template:"{{navBar}}"
    };
});


function createNavBar(userPar){
    var navBar = "<ul id=\"nav\">";

    if(userPar.isDir == 1){
        navBar +=
        "<li class=\"seccion\"><a href=\"#\">Director</a></li>";        
    }

    if(userPar.isSys == 1){
        navBar +=
        "<li class=\"seccion\"><a href=\"#\">System</a></li>";
    }

    navBar +=
    "<li class=\"seccion\"><a href=\"\" ng-click=\"logOut()\">Log Out</a></li></ul>";


    return navBar;
}
```

This is the template:

```
<html>
    <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link id="css" rel="stylesheet" href="main.css" type="text/css" />
    <script src="angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="mainApp.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="userPar" ng-app="userData" ng-controller="showUserData">
            <table id="sessionData">'.
            <tr><th colspan="6">User Data</th></tr>'.
            <tr><td class="R B">User No.:</td><td class="L">{{userPar.suID}}</td>.
            <td class="R B">Name:</td><td class="L">{{userPar.sulName}}, {{userPar.sufName}}</td>.
            <td class="R B">Access:</td><td class="L">{{userPar.utName}}</td></tr>
            </table>

            <!--<div id="navBar" otc-navbar></div>-->
            <div id="navBar" ng-bind="navBar"></div>

            </div>


    </body>
</html>
```

I tried a directive (otc-navbar) and ng-bind, but in both cases i get plain text instead of html.
How can I make it work? Thanks in advance!

Comment: check your console for javascript errors

Answer (score 1):

Use `ng-bind-html` with angular sanitize

```
<div id="navBar" ng-bind-html="navBar"></div>
```

[ng-bind-html](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngBindHtml) will evaluates your expression and inserts the resulting HTML into the element. By default, the resulting HTML content will be sanitized using the `$sanitize` service. In order to use `ngSanitize`, you need to include "`angular-sanitize.js`" in your application.

So include `angular-sanitize.js` in your page and inject the dependency to your angular module.

```
var app= angular.module('userData', ['ngSanitize']);
```

[Here](http://jsbin.com/beteyebaxu/edit?html,js,console,output) is a working sample on jsbin. :)

---

**EDIT** : As per the comment you wish ng-sanitize to **not** strip out the html attributes.

By default, `ng-sanitize` strips certain attributes out. If you really want that to not happen, You can use the [$sce](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$sce) service's `trustAsHtml` method to ***explicitly tell angular*** that the markup you are passing is safe.

[Here](http://jsbin.com/bebuzoxiju/edit?html,css,js,console,output) is a working sample

Comment: Thanks a lot! It's working now. But apparently ngSanitize strips most of attributes (including id).

Comment: @MatCat : that is the default behavior. If you don't want that behavior, you need to tell angular that whatever you are passing is safe html. See my updated answer.